# How to display received HTTP Post messages?

Tags: delphi, http-post, indy

I want to send HTTP Post messages to my Delphi application.
So, when a HTTP Post message is received, the body text should be added to a memo.

Could anyone post a code sample?

Comment: Use a TIdHTTPServer component. When it receives the POST request, the content will be in Request.Content, which you can use however you like.

Comment: @Ken White : Sorry, I don't get it...
IdHTTPServer1.Request.content doesn't exist.
And should it be processed in the OnCommandGet of the TIdHTTPServer ??

Comment: Sorry. I misspoke. I must be remembering an older version of IdHttpServer. You'll find the content of the POST in ARequestInfo, which is received in OnCommandGet.

Comment: but there is no ARequestInfo.Request.Content or something similar in ARequestInfo

Comment: I said I misspoke about Request.Content. There are several properties of ARequestInfo that have information, including .Document and .Params. You can't look through the properties to see what's there?

Comment: I did already and tried ARequestInfo.Params.GetText, ARequestInfo.Params.CommaText, ARequestInfo.Params.Text, ARequestInfo.Params.ToString, ARequestInfo.Document and 20 other things but none of them gives me the body text, sorry

Comment: There is no *body text* to a POST request. I don't know what you're asking. A POST doesn't receive an HTML page. Are you sure you know what you're looking for? Please [edit] your question to be more clear about what **specifically** you're trying to display in the memo. When you receive the POST event, what **exactly** are you trying to retrieve from that request?

Comment: thank you very much, this answer brought me to the right way... it's working now with arequestinfo.Params.Values['text'] if I call http://127.0.0.1/?text=test

Comment: It is not always safe/desirable to send text in the URL query string.  You **can** send a `POST` body.  The data will be on the `ARequestInfo.PostStream` property.  You can use the `OnCreatePostStream` event to customize the type of `TStream` class used for the `PostStream`. By default, `TMemoryStream` is used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, this was what i was looking for, thanks! The example from Dave Olson describes how to do this in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "body text" I'll assume you mean the POST data or the content that was sent in the POST request;  The actual content of the html page's body tag isn't sent.

Anyway, here's a quick and dirty little example of what I think you're looking for.  Once compiled, run the app, push the start button, then open a browser on the same machine, browse to "http://localhost/" (should pull up the little test form web page).  Then enter some data in the 2 edit fields and push the "Send" button on the little web page.  The POSTed content should appear in the memo on the form of the app.

The main form unit code:

unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdContext, IdCustomHTTPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdHTTPServer, IdHeaderList, IdGlobal;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTPServer1: TIdHTTPServer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
    procedure IdHTTPServer1CreatePostStream(AContext: TIdContext; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VPostStream: TStream);
    procedure IdHTTPServer1DoneWithPostStream(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; var VCanFree: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   idHTTPServer1.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;
  AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

var
   AForm : TStringList;
   Stream : TStream;
   S : string;

begin
   if ARequestInfo.Command = 'POST' then
      begin
         Stream := ARequestInfo.PostStream;
         if assigned(Stream) then
            begin
               Stream.Position := 0;
               S := ReadStringFromStream(Stream);

               TThread.Synchronize(nil,
                 procedure
                 begin
                    memo1.Lines.Add(S);
                 end);

            end
      end
   else
      begin
         AForm := TStringList.Create;
         try
            AForm.LoadFromFile('c:\debug\form.html');
            AResponseInfo.ContentText := AForm.Text;
         finally
           AForm.Free
         end;
      end
end;

procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1CreatePostStream(AContext: TIdContext; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VPostStream: TStream);

begin
   VPostStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1DoneWithPostStream(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; var VCanFree: Boolean);
begin
   VCanFree := false;
end;

end.
```

and the DFM:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 362
  ClientWidth = 666
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 16
    Top = 20
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Start'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 156
    Top = 8
    Width = 473
    Height = 337
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object IdHTTPServer1: TIdHTTPServer
    Bindings = <>
    OnCreatePostStream = IdHTTPServer1CreatePostStream
    OnDoneWithPostStream = IdHTTPServer1DoneWithPostStream
    OnCommandGet = IdHTTPServer1CommandGet
    Left = 76
    Top = 88
  end
end
```

and the little HTML page with a test form.  Save this little html file anywhere you want but you'll have to change line 62 to match the path to where you store it.

```
<html>

<body>

Test POST<br>

<form id="form1" action="/" method="POST">
input 1: <input id="edit1" name="edit1"><br>
input 2: <input id="edit2" name="edit2"><br>
<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for because the solution to post the string directly in the URL and get it with ARequestInfo.Params.Values is not the preferred way for me to do it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Note that the `OnCommand...` events are fired in a worker thread, so access to UI controls **must** be synchronized with the main UI thread. Also, reading a string from a `TStream`, with charset decoding, can be done using Indy's `ReadStringFromStream()` function in the `IdGlobal` unit. Don't read the raw bytes into an `AnsiString`

Comment: Ah, yes - thanks Remy - I was typing too fast :-)   I added a TThread synchronize to update the memo control.

Comment: ...and changed to use "ReadStringFromStream" as well.